# PhpOffice неправильная кодировка

Tags: php, кодировка, phpspreadsheet

Здраствуйте. Используя библиотеку `PhpOffice (PhpSpreadsheet)`, вывожу данные в `csv` файл. Проблема: вместо кирилицы в сформированом файле выводятся "кракозябры". `mb_detect_encoding` указывает указывает, что эти данные в кодировке `ASCII`, но `mb_convert_encoding($my_str, "ASCII", "UTF-8"))` не помогает, меняется только формат "кракозябр". Настройки `csv` файла:

```
    header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
    header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Customers_Export.csv');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
```

Подскажите ,в какую сторону копать. Спасибо

Comment: А можно пример кракозябр увидеть?

Answer (score 0):

Потому что строка `mb_convert_encoding($my_str, "ASCII", "UTF-8")` конвертирует данные из `UTF-8` в `ASCII`, эти значения нужно поменять местами. Читайте документацию внимательней

```php
mb_convert_encoding ( string $str , string $to_encoding [, mixed $from_encoding = mb_internal_encoding() ] ) : string
```

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Comment: Спасибо, но не помогает, все те же кракозябры. с icov тоже, попробовал на всякий случай